# Bash function to automate curl POST authentication not executing as intended

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, curl

I am using Ubuntu bash shell on a windows machine and i am trying to create a function to test my endpoints of a spring application.  First i must authenticate with the server via the following curl command. The output of the statement run is below.

```
$> curl -i -X "POST" -d"${auth}" -H"${contentType}" "${host}/login"
```

[image: output of above command]

When i copy and paste this command into a function it seems to blow up leading to non-execution of curl as intended which should have the same output as above.

```
$> function springlogin(){curl -i -X "POST" -d"${auth}" -H"${contentType}" "${host}/login";};
$> springlogin
```

[image]

What am i missing here? Is this due to some variable expansion im not aware of? Or something else entirely.

My end goal would be to use the output of this function and use it to authorize my endpoint api calls if i happen to be on my command line.

Comment: Exactly how are you using this function? Are you putting it in backquotes or `$( )`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sorry about that.  Made an edit to address.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; there has to be something else going on that you haven't mentioned. Do you have an alias defined for `springlogin`? Run `type springlogin` to make sure it's defined the way you think it is. If that doesn't clarify it, try using `set -xv` before running the command and see what it says.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson figured out it just needed to be unset before being declared again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon Davisson i figured it out.  This is something that we do at work but i didn't think to do it in my home code.  I need to unset the function in my profile before i declare it again.

```
unset springlogin
function springlogin(){curl -i -X "POST" -d"${auth}" -H"${contentType}" "${host}/login";};
```